# bash loop with GNU less that refreshes every 2 minutes

Tags: linux, bash, background-process, gnu-parallel, less-unix

I have a linux machine with a data folder and a script that produces a report xlsx spreadsheet file on the ever changing content of the folder where it is being run. I use a xlsx2tsv script to convert it to tsv text which takes less than one second. The script takes about 1 minute to produce the spreadsheet file and I want to have a terminal screen showing the results of the table in a GNU less buffer, where I can move around with the cursors, and search for content with `/search`, etc. of the most up-to-date version of the content.

At the moment I have a bash `while true; do` loop which first calculates the content of the script, then transforms it to tsv and pipes it to `GNU less`. Then in another terminal screen I have a `while true; do` loop that kills the `less` command every 2 minutes. But this leaves me with 1 minute of inactivity, where I am waiting for the spreadsheet to be updated before being able to navigate the content with `less`.

I would like to optimise this setup so that a new spreadsheet is produced in the background not when I kill the less command, but starting 1 minute before, so that the updated `less` command always gives me a working copy that I can navigate. Ideally without having to create a third terminal window for it.

Any ideas? Maybe GNU parallel?

Current setup:

```
# screen in the data folder with less command
while true; do $HOME/script -dir $PWD && xlsx2tsv $(ls $PWD/*.xlsx) 1 | column -t | less -S -N; sleep 0.5; done
# screen 2 with the less killing
while true; do pkill less; sleep 120; done
```

Comment: Can't less queue files ?

Comment: Maybe put the spreadsheet conversion into the same loop as the `pkill less` and put the output in a file on disk. Then in the first loop, wait for the file to exist and open it with less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My less man page says this about the "R" command

> R      Repaint the screen, discarding any buffered input.  Useful if the file is changing  while  it
>              is being viewed.

So, just hit <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh.

Comment: I'm assuming the filename is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
while true; do
  (sleep 0.5
   $HOME/script -dir $PWD &&
   xlsx2tsv $(ls $PWD/*.xlsx) 1 |
   column -t > new;
   mv new old;
   killall less
  ) &
  less -S -N old
done
```