# command loop in sh script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a sh script on my raspberry for a timelapse.
I've included in the script 4 command that will successively take place, each command tested and working. Now my question is: how to come back to the first command after the last one, indefinitely?

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo raspistill -w 1024 -h 768 -o /home/pi/timelapse/a%04d.jpg -t 600000 -tl 30000
sudo kill $(ps ax | grep 'timelapse' | awk '{print $1}')
sudo avconv -r 10 -i /home/pi/timelapse/a%04d.jpg -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15 timelaps$
sudo rm /home/pi/timelapse/*.jpg
```

So after `sudo rm /home/pi/timelapse/*.jpg` I want to go back to the first command.

Would you have any idea?

thanks.

Comment: man `yes` or `while` but that would be an infinite loop, what is the purpose of all this?

Comment: Never pipe `grep` to `awk`.  `awk '/timelapse/{print $1}` is the same as `grep timelapse | ... `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash loop with GNU less that refreshes every 2 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227919/bash-loop-with-gnu-less-that-refreshes-every-2-minutes) [that's an example]

Comment: If you're going to run every command in the script with `sudo`, it's probably simpler to just run the script itself with `sudo`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I wouldn't say never. for example using the `-o` on grep is far easier than acquiring the same output in awk

Comment: @123 I would agree, except that the purist in me says to never use a non-standard option like `-o`! :)  There are exceptions to the rule, but the general rule is there: don't pipe grep to awk!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do 
    ...
done
```

or, re-invoke the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

...

exec $0 "$@"
```

Frankly, either one of these seems risky in your case since you're doing no error checking at all, and you run the risk of entering a relatively fast loop of commands continuously failing.  At the very least, you should pause for a bit by using `while sleep 1;` instead of `while true;`